# Server response time is too long (ASP.NET MVC), how to find which operation is consuming so long time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pagespeed, server-response

For some reasons my server response time is 18 seconds for one of the pages in my ASP.NET MVC application.

How can I check which operation is taking that long? I want to know in what point of the application lifecycle the time is being wasted.

Is there some third-party extension for VS or may be a build in feature of the VS debugger to find out what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/), which has support for ASP.NET MVC 2, ASP.NET MVC 3 and ASP.NET MVC 4 via [Extensions](http://getglimpse.com/Packages).

You will be primarily interested in the `Execution` tab, as it will show how long each controller action is taking to execute, which will let you dig into the "slow" ones, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) or [Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). They are both free and worth the 10-15 minutes it takes to get them working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Visual Studio you're using, there is a built-in unit testing project you can add to your solution. I believe this is actually one of the options given to you when creating an ASP.NET MVC application.

You can also look into using a profiler like [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from Red Gate.